# Make web form fields line up

Tags: css, css-float, stylesheet

I have a problem with my web form fields not lining up properly.

see screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/00cw0c80e

The label is longer than normal BUT I need it to be that long. If I shorten the label, it lines up find as expected.

Anyone can help?

Thanks! :)

ps. I've looked at various samples in the net but no go.

**my css**

```
input.issu {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: 220px;
}

label.issu {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: 270px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}

select.issu {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    width: 240px;
}

br.issu {
    float: clear;
}
```

**my html code (I've tried with and without div tags)**

```
        <div>
        <label for="departingFrom" class="issu">Direct flight into Singapore from (please name city)<span class="red">* required</span></label>
        <input id="departingFrom" name="departingFrom" class="issu" value="" type="text">
        <br class="issu">
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for="additionalInfo" class="issu">Additional info(e.g. accompanying family members)<span class="red">* required</span></label>
        <input id="additionalInfo" name="additionalInfo" class="issu" value="" type="text">
        <br class="issu">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add **overflow:hidden** property to container div of label and input as follow. It will work fine.

css:

```
div{
    overflow:hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a table, putting the labels in one column, input fields in another. Then set `vertical-align` on the cells as desires (there are different interpretations on what “lining up” means in a case like this).